# Consistent view of one image on an image list in Flex for both portrait and landscape orientations

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air, adobe, tablet

I'm coding a image viewer application for tablets using Adobe Flex 4.5. Basically, I have a list with a custom item renderer that renders the images in the list. I have set up the image size to be the width/height of the tablet device in portrait (600x1024). This way, only one image can be seen at one time. The problem is that when the device orients to landscape, this design obviously screws up. My question is how can I get it to change the width/height of my images automatically when the orientation changes such that only one image is shown at a time? Or, is there a better way of approaching this?

This is my list:

```
<s:List width="600" height="1024"
        id="imageList" dataProvider="{data}" itemRenderer="{inlineRenderer}"  click="imageList_clickHandler(event)"
        verticalScrollPolicy="off" useVirtualLayout="true">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout columnWidth="600"/>
    </s:layout>
</s:List>
```

This is the item renderer:

```
<s:Scroller width="600" height="1024">
                <s:Group>
                    <s:Image source="{data.imageurl}" width="600" height="1024"
                                   contentLoader="{FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.imageCache}"/>
                </s:Group> </s:Scroller>
```

Comment: So much looks wrong here.  Why do you need a scroller in the renderer? Why are you specifying an explicit height and width in the renderer (and on the list)?  That will most likely not be the least bit cross-device.  Adobe discourages the use of MXML Renderers for mobile devices.  And binding in a renderer is horrible for performance; which is important on a mobile device.  Why are you using a list if you plan to only display one item at once?  Just use a single Image and change the source as users "Scroll" through the list.

Comment: In terms of your question' perhaps you just need to maintain aspect ratio on the image and change the height and width values when the orientation changes.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I am using a scroller because I want to use the zoom gesture to zoom the image and be able to scroll through it. I'll change it to an image alone too instead of a complex List. In the docs, I read that a list doesn't render the other components that are not shown so I thought there won't be any performance issues. I know hard-coding the width/height is bad design, I should've used percentages. Also, what do you suggest is better instead of Renderers and how am I supposed to avoid binding?

Comment: Correct, the List doesn't render components not displayed. But, if you're only displaying one at a time; I'm not sure I'd use a List.  Avoid binding in renderers by listening to the dataChange event, and manually making your changes in the event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to create an image only item renderer that handles orientation changes automatically:

```
<s:List id="list" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <fx:String>http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png</fx:String>
            <fx:String>http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png</fx:String>
            <fx:String>http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png</fx:String>
            <fx:String>http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png</fx:String>
            <fx:String>http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png</fx:String>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <s:ItemRenderer width="{outerDocument.list.width}" 
                            height="{outerDocument.list.height}">
                <fx:Script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        import spark.core.ContentCache;
                        [Bindable]
                        public static var imageCache:ContentCache = new ContentCache();

                        override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                            super.data = value;
                            bitmapImage.source = data;
                        }
                    ]]>
                </fx:Script>
                <s:BitmapImage id="bitmapImage" contentLoader="{imageCache}" width="100%" height="100%" />
            </s:ItemRenderer>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

This renderer should perform pretty well even tho it is written in MXML because it follows some simple optimization rules (see http://flexponential.com/2011/04/20/flex-performance-tips-tricks/), but you'll want to test it in your application to make sure it feels ok.

In general Adobe recommends writing item renderers in ActionScript by extending LabelItemRenderer or IconItemRenderer for best performance.  If the renderer above isn't fast enough for you then you might want to check out https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-30043 for a discussion on the current problem and workaround to doing this with IconItemRenderer.